# CellularpDriver Program

Tags: java

When I enter a value for the Cost such as 90.00, the code should display 'Price is too low'. If I put in a value that is more than 850.00 it still gives me the same output. Maybe my problem is in the if statement. Can someone help me with this problem? Thank you.

```
 package cellularpdriver;

    public class CellularPDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Phone information = new Phone();

        information.setCost(950.00);

        information.setNetwork("3G");

        information.setModel("Samsung");

        if (information.setCost < 850.00) {
            System.out.println("Price is too low");

        } else {

            System.out.println("The Cost of the phone is: $" + information.getCost());

        }

        System.out.println("The Network of the phone is: " + information.getNetwork());
        System.out.println("The Model of the phone is: " + information.getModel());
        }

    }
```

Comment: this isn't javascript

Comment: also how does `information.setCost` compile when you have `information.setCost(950.00)` as a function call? do you really also have a `setCost` public field in you phone class?

Comment: @KevinL I have double setCost; in my phone class